# React - i want to blur or darken all page except specific element when user miss that one specific element to fill in page

Tags: reactjs, view, blur, blurry, getboundingclientrect

Basically i want the user to **focus** on that element where they make mistake or jump that element. My main goal is attract user's attention with better UI

I try to get position of that element with `getBoundingClientRect()` ,
then try to use **"react-native-blur"**

Is it right way to do this or how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to monitor changes and validate field upon certain event. It's easiest to use library such as [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form). It automatically focuses on first field with error

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-j5wxo)